# How do I use multiple schemas in an Oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Problem: Needing to use data in two (or more) different schemas or connections in Oracle SQL Developer. For example: Invoice data in the finance schema, and sales data in the inventory schema. Needing to get to product info for the invoice data, via a join of a invoiced product to the product in the inventory schema.

I am new to Oracle, coming from SQL Server. In T-SQL, I would just put the database name or the IP address. For example (random, made-up IP):

```
[555.00.12302].Sales_DB.Item_Table.Item_Price_Column
```

In SQL Developer for Oracle (using 11g), I cannot figure out how to call another connection or schema, in a select query, to join in a table from that schema. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure you mean a tablespace and not a schema?

Comment: I believe its the tablespace. However, the lingo here might be wrong. They are the items below the Connections. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: You don't specify (or reference) tablespaces in a query (or a stored procedure). You do mean schema or even instance, but definitely not tablespace (which compares to a filegroup in SQL Server). To reference a table in a different Oracle _instance_ you will need a to create a [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF01205). Btw: PL/SQL is **exclusively** used for stored procedures (or anonymous PL/SQL blocks). Queries, DML, DDL etc are just "SQL"

Comment: Yes, per the below answer, I am talking about schema, NOT tablespace. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that you don't mean "tablespace"-- you don't reference the tablespace in which an object is stored when you query it.  Some objects are stored in multiple tablespaces.  You might mean "schema" or you might mean "database" where a schema in Oracle is most similar to a database in SQL Server.

If you want to access a table stored in a different schema in the same database

```
select *
  from schema_name.table_name
```

assuming you have privileges on `table_name` in the `schema_name` schema.  You can create public or private synonyms or change your session's `current_schema` to avoid prefixing the schema name but that's all just syntactic sugar for the fully qualified name.

If you really want to access data stored in a different database, then you'd need to create a database link.  This is an object that is stored in the database that creates a connection to another database.  There are lots of options when creating a database link.  One option, assuming the same user exists on both databases with the same password in each

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK my_link
  CONNECT TO CURRENT_USER
  USING '<<TNS alias of remote database>>';

SELECT *
  FROM schema_name.table_name@my_link;
```

Comment: Actually, Justin, if the same user didn't exist on both databases, this becomes much harder, correct? My companies standard is to have one login per database (I know...). That everyone uses.

Comment: Different, yes.  You can declare the database link to connect with a fixed username and a fixed password to another database.  That's generally a security concern, though, since now anyone with access to the database link can act as the remote user in the remote database with very little audit trail.  If you're already violating every security rule by having everyone log in to the source system as the same user, though, presumably a fixed username in a database link doesn't make things much less secure.